# Laravel 5.2 - get images of item in blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

My controller is:

```
public function index()

{

$details= Food::all();

return view('details.index', compact('details'));

}

public function show($Food_id)

{

 $detail=Food::findOrFail($Food_id);

 return view('details.show', compact('detail'));

}
```

My index.blade.php is:

```
<h1>Details</h1>

<hr/>  


@foreach($details as $detail)

<detail>

<h2>

<a href="/details/{{$detail->Food_id}}">{{$detail->FoodName}}

</a>

</h2>

</detail>

@endforeach
```

And my show.blade.php is:

```
 <h1 align="center">{{$detail -> FoodName}}</h1>

<detail>

<h3><p>Name:</h3><h4>{{$detail->FoodName}}</h4></p>
```

I want to show the images of food items that are stored in public/uploads folder.How I can get images to show them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each `food` object holds an `image` property, you can display the uploaded image by using Laravel's `asset` helper.

```
@foreach($details as $detail)

<detail>

    <h2>

    <a href="/details/{{$detail->Food_id}}">{{$detail->FoodName}}</a>

    </h2>

    // food photo
    <p><img src="{{ asset('uploads/'.$detail->image) }}" /><p>

</detail>

@endforeach
```

Comment: I get images in index page but how I can show these images on show page.

Comment: _how I can show these images on show page_. You're trying to show only the image of that current food that you're viewing right or is it the images of all the food that you listed on the index page?

Comment: I am trying to show the image of only current food that I have clicked.

Comment: Ohh, you can display the image the same way. `<img src="{{ asset('uploads/'.$detail->image) }}" />`. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I mean to say food items are listed on webpage and i want that when i click on some item it gives me details of only that food with details.

Comment: Yeah, I understand and it should work if you do that. Are there any console errors?

Comment: ok i have done that.another problem is that i want to show details directly from homepage by clicking on listed food items.Means that i don't want details page in mid.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, so you want to show the food details in the homepage itself without redirecting to another page? If yes, then i think you should send an ajax request to the server to get the food details and display the returned data in some part of the homepage or in a modal.

Comment: No,my food items are listed on homepage having button each item,when i clicked on some item it open a page that is index.blade in which again all that food items are shown having links,then i clicked on some item it shows me details.But i want that from homepage when i clicked on some item it shows me details & not to redirect me index page having links of food items.

Comment: My routes are:Route::get('details', 'DetailsController@index'); AND
Route::get('details/{FoodName}', 'DetailsController@show');

Comment: And onclick on button from view is "onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/details/'" "

Comment: You forgot put the id of the food in this _"onclick="window.location='localhost:8000/details/'";_ That's why it redirects back to the index page. Or you could just try changing your current button to this instead. `<a href="/details/{{$detail->Food_id}}" class="your-btn-classes-here">View Food</a>`

Comment: I have already tried this,but from homepage it gives error like: Undefined variable: detail

Comment: I tried this "onclick="window.location='localhost:8000/details/{FoodName}'" but it gives me error like: "No query results for model [App\Food]."